# Change leftmark in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, numbering, punctuation, fancyhdr

Can anyone tell me how, in the minimal example pasted below, I can achieve that the dot after Appendix in the header disappears? I understand that it is there because I simply made the number of the `appendix` invisible.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{fancy} 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{appendices}
   {\def\thechapter{}\chapter{This and that}}
   \blindtext
   \newpage
   \blindtext
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

EDIT by ldpw: Maybe it would be even better if the dot was not removed but if it was put directly behind Appendix (that is, without the blank space between appendix and the dot):

APPENDIX   . THIS AND THAT  --> APPENDIX. THIS AND THAT

Answer (score 3):

Change also the definition of `\chaptermark`:

```
\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter
\def\chaptermark#1{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp. \  #1}}{}}
\def\thechapter{}
\makeatother
\chapter{This and that}
\blindtext
\newpage
\blindtext
\end{appendices}
```

The heading is controlled by `\chaptermark`, which is responsible to issue a suitable `\markboth` or `\markright` command. The usual definition of `\chaptermark` given by `fancyhdr` is

```
\def\chaptermark#1{%
  \markboth{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne
        \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
      \fi
      ##1%
    }}{}%
}
```

where `\@chapapp` becomes `\chaptername` or `\appendixname`, depending on where it's issued. So you see the source of the space before the period, which is there for separating the name (Chapter or Appendix) from the number.

Your case seems to be a common one: you have only one appendix, so you don't want it appears as "Appendix A". Locally redefining `\thechapter` removes the "A", but not the space in the heading, so we redefine also `\chaptermark`.

It's not necessary to enclose those redefinitions inside a group, because the surrounding `appendices` environment will restore the normal definitions at its end (and they actually shouldn't be needed any more, so also without the `appendices` environment the group isn't necessary).

Comment: Hi egreg! That works fine. Thanks! Can you maybe give a few explanations on your code so that the next time I have a similar problem I can solve it myself? That would be great.

Comment: Why markboth and not leftmark?

Comment: @lpdbw That's how `fancyhdr` does. With only the `report` definition and oneside printing, probably `\markright` instead of `\markboth` should be used.

Comment: AH, OK ... Then I seem to have misunderstood the explanations in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout#Customising_with_fancyhdr